# problema TimeOut con WCF

Tags: c#, webservice, wcf

quisiera que me puedan ayudar,
estoy realizando un servicio `SOAP` en `WCF` por la cual el problema se cae por **timeout**  del servicio porque tengo un foreach de 14 mil registro y cada uno realiza algo.
Pero si pasa lo 5 min sale un mensaje de error que indica timeout 00:05:00

Lo que he realizado en el web.config ya le agregue el tiempo de espera pero de igual manera si pasa en 5 min sale ese mensaje de `TimeOut`

```
<binding name="ServicioGenerarFlujoSPBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="80000000" maxBufferSize="80000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="80000000" closeTimeout="20:00:00" openTimeout="20:00:00" receiveTimeout="20:00:00" sendTimeout="20:00:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<service name="CalculosBeneficios.Aplicacion.WCF.Servicio.SP.ServicioFlujoSP">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:20007/ServicioEPV.FlujosSP.CalculosBeneficios" 
                  binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicioGenerarFlujoSPBinding" 
          contract="CalculosBeneficios.Aplicacion.Contrato.Servicio.SP.IServicioGenerarFlujosSP">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:20007/ServicioEPV.FlujosSP.CalculosBeneficios" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>


<bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="ServicioGenerarFlujoSPBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="20:00:00" openTimeout="20:00:00" receiveTimeout="20:00:00" sendTimeout="20:00:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: Por favor escribí el código en lugar de pegar una captura de pantalla..

Comment: @MaxPinto no se esta respetando los 20 min que le colocado y siempre se cae cuando pasa los 5 min

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal hermano lo que pasa es que estoy en otro servidor y no se puede copiar y pegar.

Comment: No subas imagenes del codigo por favor, simplemente copia y pegalo.

Comment: @ZottoSL estoy en otro servidor y en el otro servidor no cuento con inter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ademas de definir el timeout en el config del cliente tambien deberias hacerlo en el servidor

```
<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpsBindingConfig" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
    <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

valida como en el config del server se define el `sendTimeout`

Ademas presta atencion que ese binding es el que uses para exponer el servicio

[How to: Increase the timeout value of a WCF service](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/wcf-report-service-increasing-timeout)

[Increasing the timeout value in a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424358/increasing-the-timeout-value-in-a-wcf-service)

Comment: Tutitini gracias por responder lo coloque donde estaba en el wcf

Comment: pero estas modificando el config del servidor o del cliente ?

Comment: tutini como diferencio eso es que yo tengo dos proyecto uno que ese servicio se instala como un servicio de window y es ahi donde esta configurado pero en el mismo wcf no esta

Comment: el servidor es quien explone servicio, el que implementa la interfaz del wcf, el cliente es donde realizaste la service reference y se creo el codigo del proxy, hay config en ambos extremos, por eso mencionaba donde estabas modificando

Comment: tutini lo coloque en el servidor , ya que estoy haciendo en una arquitectura dominio.
ya que no le colocado en el cliente ya que es en un web api que va ser consumida como service reference , y ahora no lo estoy usando solo lo estoy probando desde wcftestclient

Comment: podrias publicar el binfing completo (no como imagen) incluido el <services>, porque alli veo que defines unas 20 hs, si estas esperando que el servicio demore tanto no creo que sea conveniente que lo ejecutes como parte del servicio, sino que deberias desacoplar y hacer que un job realice el trabajo. Por job hago referencia a un windows service o similar que tome la operacion y pueda estae trabajando sin un tiempo limite

Comment: Tutini ya modifique y coloque lo que me pediste

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87380/discussion-between-pierodev-and-leandro-tuttini).

Comment: me parece que el problema puede ser causado por WcfTestClient, analiza que este permite definir un config para definir tambien el timeout del lado del cliente  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476761/wcf-service-throwing-a-timeout-error-when-using-wcftestclient

Comment: aqui tambien https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-wcf-services/9781449382476/ch01s10.html  analiza la Figure 1-18 veras que hay un Config File, del lado del cliente tambien hay un timeout, sino prueba el servicio creando una app de consola y agregando el service reference